# How to select the most recent record in Rails that's via a join to another table with multiple records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of employees and another table of employments. A given employee can have one or more employments. I want to return a relation of employees but joining with their most recent employment, based on a `created_at` date on the employment.

I put a sqlfiddle in place: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b0a3d/2 but that's the basic SQL so it returns a single row for each employee and with the employment data for that employee that corresponds to their *latest* employment.

NOTE: the sqlfiddle is me thinking about the problem from a SQL perspective, but what I really am after is how to do this via Ruby on Rails. How to join `Employee` records with `Employment` records but only pulling the latest `Employment` record. (hopefully this helps clarify).

So `Employee.includes(:employments)` basically does what the sqlfiddle does.

I need something a bit fancier to join the employee and employment data (with latest employment).

I welcome any thoughts.

Comment: Their latest employment, or latest active employment?

Comment: their latest employment

Comment: I think I worded this question a bit too vague. I created a new SO question that is much simpler and gets to the heart of my confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551675/how-do-i-build-an-arel-query-in-ruby-on-rails-that-joins-on-the-max-of-a-has-man

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on` to solve this top-1-per-group problem:

```
select distinct on(e.id) e.id, e.name, m.created, m.active
from employees e
inner join employments m on m.employee_id = e.id;
order by e.id, m.created desc;
```

In **[your DB Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b0a3d/6)**, this produces:

```
id  name created    active
1   Dan  2019-10-23 false
2   Sam  2019-07-11 true
3   Joe  2019-03-13 false
```

Comment: Thank you GMB! That helps. I guess perhaps I wasn't fully clear, though. I'm hoping to do this in Ruby on Rails, not as pure SQL.

Comment: @DanSharp: ah ok, my bad. The db fiddle was appealing. You should probably edit your question to show your current ruby code, so it is unambiguous what you want.

Comment: Adding the `distinct on()` in your rails code should be fairly trivial, though.

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you want -

```
Employee.joins(:employments)
        .select(:id, :name, 'employments.created', 'employments.active')
        .order('employments.created_at desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first find the `MAX(created)` of each employment in `Employment` table by a sub-query then `inner join` the result with `Employee` table.

```
subquery = """
SELECT employments.employee_id, MAX(created)
FROM employments
GROUP BY employments.employee_id
"""

Employee.joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery}) AS t ON t.employee_id = employees.id")
```